# How to get the path of current worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro as an add-in, and I need to get the path of the current worksheet on which it is being executed. How do I do this? How do I get the file path (just the directory)?

Comment: do you mean that, given a worksheet, you want to know the folder where the parent workbook is saved?

Answer (score 343, accepted):

Use `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` for just the path itself (without the workbook name) or `Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName` for the path *with* the workbook name.

Comment: Activeworkbook depends on which workbook is active. USe Thisworkbook.path

Comment: Both are useful in different situations, of course. I took the original question to mean that the macro resided in an add-in workbook (which would be ThisWorkbook.path), but needed to run code against other workbooks as needed by the user (which would be ActiveWorkbook.path).

Comment: Should always be explicit - if it's this workbook, it should be application.thisworkbook.path. If it's a workbook being opened, the name should be defined with a set, then application.Variablename.path (or fullpath, depending).

Comment: @Selkie If the *code itself* opens the workbook, then sure. But if this is simply a helper macro that resides in an add-in workbook and needs to operate on whichever workbook the user currently has open when they invoke the macro, then `ActiveWorkbook` is what is needed.

Comment: `Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Path` only works if the file has been saved at least once.  Also, if the file has never been saved, `Excel.ActiveWorkbook.FullName` only returns the file name.  Might be a good idea to [check if the workbook has ever been saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530313/can-vba-determine-if-an-excel-workbook-has-ever-been-saved).

Comment: Note that if the Workbook is saved on OneDrive or inside a directory synchronized by OneDrive, this solution will return a URL, not the local path of the Workbook. A solution to get the local path on this case is presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).

Answer (score 41):

Always nice to have:

```
Dim myPath As String     
Dim folderPath As String 

folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path    
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Answer (score 36):

If you want to get the path of the workbook from where the macro is being executed - use

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
```

`Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` can sometimes produce unexpected results (e.g. if your macro switches between multiple workbooks).

Comment: @avalanche1.That is totally correct, activeworkbook raised alot of unexpected results with me

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way

```
path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

Comment: Your way would be good if you could add the &"\" at the very end.

myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I built a solution that I'm going to share. Below is the function in VBA for Excel GetLocalPath(), which gets the local path of the ActiveWorkbook:

`Function GetLocalPath() As String

```
Dim sRowPath    As String
Dim sLocalPath  As String
Dim iFindhttp   As Integer

sRowPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

If LCase(Left(sRowPath, 4)) = "http" Then
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    sLocalPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(sRowPath)
    iFindhttp = InStr(LCase(sLocalPath), "\http")
    sLocalPath = Left(sLocalPath, iFindhttp - 1)
    Set fso = Nothing
Else
    sLocalPath = sRowPath
End If
        
GetLocalPath = sLocalPath
```

End Function`

Comment: Hi @JulioGracia, the problem you are addressing is how to convert a OneDrive Url to a local path. Unfortunately, your function doesn't work for any of the test cases I set up for such functions. If you are interested in a better solution for this problem, take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).

Comment: thanks for your comment, it was usefull for me, and I confirm the solution of Julio didn't work in my case, but the solution mentionned in the link that you shared works fine till now