# How to get current directory without using VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Is possible get current directory without using VBA? (to avoid using macros)

I know that is possible via [VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba), but I am trying to avoid using macros in my document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

This will get local physical path. If file is on a remote machine, it will return the network path.

```
=INFO("DIRECTORY")
```

This will get network path (with machine name). **NOTE:** for me it just returns the networked My Directory folder from **ANY** file it is called from. Be careful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [INFO](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/info-function-HP010342610.aspx) formula to get path of the current directory or folder. Just write it in any cell

```
 =INFO("directory")
```

Comment: That gives the executing path, so the root folder of Excel

Comment: It give `Path of the current directory or folder.` see http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/info-function-HP010342610.aspx

Comment: I'm wrong, sorry, I tried INFO and it came back with the working directory. Second attempt came back with the directory the document is in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the forumula

```
 =CELL("filename", A1)
```

then substring it

UPDATE: the better solution is

```
 =INFO("DIRECTORY")
```