# Word vba how to save picture from image object to file?

Tags: image, vba, ms-word, userform

I have an image object on a userform. I want to save the picture from that image object into a file. I see many examples of how to load a picture into an image object, but none the other way around.

I tried `stdole.SavePicture obj.Picture, strFilePath`, but that only works for button objects.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. What is not working?

Comment: Anybody have anything???

Answer (score 2):

First create a Chart.  Second place the picture in the Chart.  Finally export the Chart.

**EDIT#1**

For sample code see:

[Save Picture with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333558/export-pictures-excel-vba)

Comment: @Chuck  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Sorry, I'm using WORD, not Excel. And the image object is on a form, not on the document (or on an Excel worksheet).

Comment: Yes, yours would work for Excel, because it has the chart object that happens to do what I need. But Word doesn't have that. I've been searching for an answer, but a lot of Excel answers keep coming up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but I tried casting the Picture object to an IPictureDisp object to pass it to the stdoleSavePicture function, and it worked for me.

Here's the code:

```
Dim pic As IPictureDisp

Set pic = myForm.Image1.Picture

stdole.SavePicture pic, "C:\myfile.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I enlist PowerPoint to do this. Here's a macro from a recent project that exported a map of the world:

```
Public Sub ExportMap()
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShapeRange As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
Dim Path$, File$
Dim oRange As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  myDate$ = Format(Date, "m-d-yyyy")
  Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  Path$ = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
  File$ = "WorldMap " & myDate$ & ".png"
  Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(msoFalse)
  
  Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("WholeMap").Range
  oRange.CopyAsPicture
  
  Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
  On Error Resume Next
  With pptPres.PageSetup
    .SlideSize = 7
    .SlideWidth = 1150
    .SlideHeight = 590
  End With
  Set pptShapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoFalse)
  
  pptSlide.Export Path$ & File$, "PNG"
  
  pptApp.Quit
  
  Set pptPres = Nothing
  Set pptApp = Nothing
  Set pptSlide = Nothing
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "All done! Check the folder containing this template for a file called '" & File$ & "'."
End Sub
```