# Reference of the SavePicture statement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Based on examples I have seen how to use:

`SavePicture Picture:= pic As IPictureDisp, FileName:=fullPathName As String`

But I can't find official information from Microsoft anywhere.

Could someone provide me with a link to the official documentation on the SavePicture instruction?

Thank you.
Greetings.

I have done a search without success.

Comment: There is no `SavePicture`-command in Excel VBA. Maybe you saw this https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/savepicture-statement.htm ? Or do you mean `Shape.SaveAsPicture`?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333558/export-pictures-excel-vba)  is helpful to export shapes from Excel.

Comment: This post looks comprehensive. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/vba-save-as-picture-file-excel/#:~:text=Save%20Shape%20As%20A%20PNG%20File%20%5BVBA%20Code%5D,and%20save%20to%20the%20user%E2%80%99s%20desktop%20More%20items

Comment: FunThomas, Of course it exists as such, I'm using it, but it doesn't appear in the Instructions reference, or anywhere else in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Taller and MT1. I had already seen those pages. But I'm not referring to the solution of exporting graphics.