# set the value of a string to the name of the excel file you are applying the code to

Tags: vba, excel

As the title says, I want to get the name of the file saved as a string. 
I have

```
wstitle = Application.Caller.Worksheet.name
```

and it forces the n to lower case and doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the path of current worksheet in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba)

Comment: It would seem that the application call is referencing a different form of `.Name` than one of these standard calls. `wstitle = ThisWorkbook.Name` or `wstitle = ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim s As String
    s = ThisWorkbook.Name
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

will display something like:

```
Book1.xlsm
```

*NOTE:*

The *Path* is omitted, but the *extension* is included.
*ThisWorkbook* is the workbook containing the code.