# VBA Create a new workbook with a button click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that creates a new workbook when pressing a button on the already existing workbook. I would like to save the newly created workbook in the same folder as the exiting workbook and give it a new name? Could somebody help me please?

Thank you very much in advance!

That's the code I have until now but it doesn't work as I want it (object not found and doesn't save it in the same folder):

```
Sub CreateNewWorkBook()

'Adding New Workbook
Workbooks.Add
'Saving the Workbook
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\Test.xls"
 ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following code from:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221273(v=office.11).aspx

```
Sub AddNew()
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = "All Sales" 'You can modify this value.
        .Subject = "Sales" 'You can modify this value.
        .SaveAs Filename:="Allsales.xls"
    End With
End Sub
```

To get the path of the file there is already a question about that:

> [How to get the path of current worksheet in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba)